# SQL - Total tables for scoring application

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access, sum

I will have several tables that will be named along the lines of:

```
TUGOFWAR_Y9

TUGOFWAR_Y10
```

.... And so on for each year of the school

Each table will look like:

```
HOUSE | PLACE | POINTS

A         1       8
B         3       4
C         2       6
D         4       2
```

Basically there will be a load of tables like this that record the place of houses in tug of war's and when the user enters the place each house came the points automatically add.

I already have that aspect working. What I need is a total table. As there will not just be Tug of war, I want a total table for each venue. For example a tug of war total table and a 100m sprint total table.

The table tugofwartotal looks like this empty for example

```
HOUSE | TOTAL

A         0
B         0
C         0
D         0
```

I would like SQL commands that will get the points scored from each tug of war table and put the total into the total tables.

I am doing this in VB.net

Comment: Bad design I'd say. Use one table with the year as a column instead of a table for every year. Maybe even one for all disciplines if there are also just place and points columns for them. Also the place a is dependent on the points I suspect, so it shouldn't be in the tables at all but calculate in queries.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a suggested table design. One table, no Place, no totals. Added an ID column as a Primary Key. Should be an identity (auto-number) Integer.

Table Name: EventScores

```
RecID | House | Points | Event | Year
```

Query it:

```
Select House, 
       Sum(Points) As TotalPoints 
From EventScores 
Where Event = "TugOfWar" 
Group By House 
Order By House;
```

If you wanted to get them by place:

```
Select House,
       Points 
From EventScores 
Where Event = "TugOfWar"  
  And Year = 2018 
Order By Points DESC;
```

There is the design and the SQL statement examples. Now you write the code.

Disclaimer: I am not a DBA so this is just what I remember from normalization.